# Change Toolbar icon in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, toolbar, xamarin.forms

It's gotta be right in front of me, but I can't find it.  I'm using Xamarin.Forms targeting Android (to start) and have a Toolbar.  I'd like to change one of the ToolbarItems' icon during the course of the application to indicate background work progress.

Where do I find a reference back to the **ToolbarItem** in question (outside of the App class where it was set) so I can update its icon property?

I'm also open to suggestions on other ways to provide a similar visual indicator.  TIA!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Master details page, you can do by this code.

```
if (((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).ToolbarItems.Count > 0)
{ 
    ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).ToolbarItems[0].Icon = Constants.deviceIcon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best solution, but I was able to solve the problem by declaring the ToolbarItem static in App.cs, which made it accessible where I needed it.